# What is sort of standard torrent client for MacOS (2019-2020)?

Tags: software-recommendation, torrent

I have been using uTorrent for years, both for Mac and Windows.

But uTorrent stopped working with new MacOS Catalina, it is not compatible with new MacOS.

I started to google and found out that uTorrent was never meant for MacOS.

What is sort of standard torrent client for MacOS? Preferably with similar functionality as uTorrent, I got used to it and wouldn't want to learn new software.

Comment: Those who put my Q on hold: GET OUT of my question, snobs! It is related to Apple community, got that?

Answer (score 2):

[Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com/) is the app that I have most often heard people talk about when “torrents on the Mac” comes up.

I don’t know uTorrent, so I can’t speak to whether its functionality is the same as Transmission, but it is very straightforward to use.

Transmission is donation-ware, so you can download and try it out for free.